# Compare one ArrayList and combine common elements

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, matching

I've been working on an algorithm to loop through one ArrayList containing a custom object. I'm now on hour 20 and I've gotten almost nowhere.

```
    ArrayList<TicketItem> all = new ArrayList<>();

    // ... 'all' gets filled here ... //

    ArrayList<TicketItem> allCopy = new ArrayList<>(all);
    for (int i = allCopy.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        TicketItem last = allCopy.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < all.size(); j++) {
            TicketItem compare = all.get(j);
            if (last.getInt(TicketItem.TICKET_ITEM_ID) != compare.getInt(TicketItem.TICKET_ITEM_ID)) {
                if (last.canBeGrouped(compare)) {
                    last.put(TicketItem.TICKET_ITEM_NUMBER, compare.getInteger(TicketItem.TICKET_ITEM_NUMBER));
                    allCopy.set(i, last);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works when it wants to and to be honest, it's probably really ugly. I just can't get my head around a better option.

The important method inside TicketItem is this one:

```
public boolean canBeGrouped(TicketItem other) {
    if (other == null)
        return false;
    if (getBoolean(TicketItem.TICKET_ITEM_VOID))
        return false;
    if (other.getBoolean(TicketItem.TICKET_ITEM_VOID))
        return false;
    if (getInteger(TicketItem.MENU_ITEM) == null)
        return false;
    if (getInteger(TicketItem.MENU_ITEM).equals(other.getInteger(TicketItem.MENU_ITEM))
            && getBigDecimal(TicketItem.TICKET_ITEM_TOTAL).compareTo(
                    other.getBigDecimal(TicketItem.TICKET_ITEM_TOTAL)) == 0) {
        ArrayList<TicketItemModifier> mThis = getModifiers();
        ArrayList<TicketItemModifier> mOther = other.getModifiers();
        if (mThis == null && mOther == null)
            return true;
        if (mThis != null && mOther != null) {
            if (mThis.size() == mOther.size()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mThis.size(); i++) {
                    TicketItemModifier m1 = mThis.get(i);
                    TicketItemModifier m2 = mOther.get(i);
                    Integer m1MenuModifierId = m1.getInteger(TicketItemModifier.MENU_MODIFIER_ID);
                    Integer m2MenuModifierId = m2.getInteger(TicketItemModifier.MENU_MODIFIER_ID);
                    if (!(m1MenuModifierId != null && m2MenuModifierId != null && m1MenuModifierId
                            .equals(m2MenuModifierId))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Again, super ugly especially the for loop in there that works when it wants to. If need be I can modify hashCode and equals methods for both classes TicketItem and TicketItemModifier, however I would like to stay away from those two methods and do something along the lines of Comparable classes because just because they can be grouped does not mean they are equal.

What I want to do basically is go through one ArrayList filled with TicketItem objects and when two can be grouped I need to change the TicketItem object to match it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you create a new property or function like TickeItemCode which should be string concatenation of  MENU_ITEM+ "-"+ TICKET_ITEM_TOTAL+ "-" + MENU_MODIFIER_IDs in modifiers list. you can filter the list to remove items where  TICKET_ITEM_VOID is true and then sort by new property TickeItemCode and do grouping. This way you can reduce your time from n^2 to nlogn

Comment: This is genius, why I never thought of it is beyond me, however, this still leaves me with fixing the for loop method, unless you think that's the only way.

Comment: you may create additional dictionary data structure holding key and first object found under that key, this way you will need just one loop